# How to change the block chain file path to (default)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

When I change the block link path from the default to another path, I always get an error: the connected background process is not compatible with the current GUI wallet, and there is no select button when I want to change back to the default path.

Since I changed the default path, my background process has always been the following（It doesn't matter whether you're using simple mode or advanced mode）:

16382 ?? 0:00.91 /Users/name/Downloads/monero-gui-v0.15.0.2/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monerod --detach --data-dir /Users/name/.bitmonero --bootstrap-daemon-address auto --no-sync --check-updates disabled --max-concurrency 4

My GUI wallet is the MAC version, so the default path is in the $Home/.bitmonero folder, but even if I manually set this path, it didn't solve the problem I'd been having. And even if I were to recreate a new wallet, it wouldn't help.

When creating a new wallet, the block link path shows the path I set instead of the word (default), and the background process is the same as above. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I've use symbolic links on linux.  Don't see why Mac (its just *nix with training wheels) would complain.  I put a symbolic link in the ~/bitmonero/lmdb  pointing to the actual file location.  ln -s <actual file> <link name>

Comment: A reset button will be added in a future version. https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/pull/2792